# How do they tell what environment variable name is in windows' System variables

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I am sorry if this question is silly.
 I have no problems with setting environment variables, but I am curious to know the answer.
I searched Google but I didn't find information.

For example they tell set the variable name for Java to **JAVA_HOME**, and for apache tomcat set the variable name to **CATALINA_HOME**

How do they know it is **JAVA_HOME** and **CATALINA_HOME**?
Is there a way to know that myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"They" wrote code that reads environment variables with those names.

Therefore, "they" can tell you to set those names.

Comment: Thanks. I want to know more: If I download apache tomcat for the first time. Then is there a way to find out **CATALINA_HOME** without searching Google.